# Problema comparando horas en php

Tags: php, date, datetime, comparaciones, horas

Tengo este codigo hecho en php.

La idea es saber si ha pasado media hora desde la ultima insercion a Mysql

```html
$Ahora = new DateTime("now");
$Nuevofichaje = new DateTime($UltimaEntrada); 
$Nuevofichaje->modify('+30 minute');

 if ($Ahora > $Nuevofichaje) { echo "Hola"; }
```

En principio todo me funcina menos la condicion que compara la hora actual con la hora que traigo de la base de datos.

El caso es que no se que error de sintaxis estoy teniendo que me dice que la constante hola falla, pero me da que el fallo esta en la comparacion de las horas que me debe faltar algo.

Tengo definido el time zone en date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");

LLevo como 2H intentando probar distintas formas y lo unico que he conseguido que me de un "true" o "False" es haciendo un var_dump a var_dump($Ahora > $Nuevofichaje); pero claro que me salga en pantalla no me vale de mucho, lo que quiero es guardar una variable con el si o el no y ejecutar una parte de codigo o no segun el resultado.

Mil gracias de antemano y perdon por mi ignorancia.

Comment: `$UltimaEntrada` que contiene exactamente? Por ahí el formato de esa fecha no es compatible con lo que pide `DateTime`. Probá hacer un `var_dump($UltimaEntrada); exit;` justo después de definirla y fijate si está haciendo algo. Sino vas a tener que probar con [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: Revisa el timezone de un `phpinfo()` y desde php el resultado de la consulta `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;`

Comment: @azeós lo he hecho y me da como resultado string(7) "3:00 pm"

Comment: @Sal la tengo definida en date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");

Comment: @Killpe `$UltimaEntrada` que contiene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) para luego calcular la diferencia entre 2 fechas en segundos:

```php
php > $dt1 = strtotime('2022-06-28 09:01:18');
php > $dt2 = strtotime('2022-06-28 11:14:13');
php > echo $dt2 - $dt1;
7975 // segundos
```

30 minutos es `30*60 = 1800seg` . También debes resolver las diferencias de zona horaria, si las hay, como han mencionados otros. Entonces la lógica de tu código puede ser:

```php
$UltimaEntrada = '2022-06-28 09:15:46'; // <-- valor de muestra
if((strtotime("now") - strtotime($UltimaEntrada)) > 1800) {
    echo 'La diferencia es mayor a 30 minutos';
}
```

Comment: Genial, me gusta mas esta forma. Un millon de gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto dandole formato otra vez a $Nuevofichaje usando:

if ($Ahora > $Nuevofichaje->format('H:i')) { echo "Hola"; }

No se si habrá una forma algo mas elegante de hacerlo.

Pero bueno pongo la solucion temporal por si a alguien le sirve